# How to combine List and Library into one view in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, library

I really need help. I know in "SharePoint 2010" we could combine the view of List and Library into one view, but now in "SharePoint Online" I do not know how. I do not want to export or import data from excel. I want to be able to pull the data from my List and Library data in SharePoint. I do not want to export and or import anything. I want to be able to use the data from the List and Library from my SharePoint Online only.  Is there a way to combine the different data into one view? I do not know if I have to use SharePoint Designer, a specific web app part, or there is a setting that I am not trying?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! You can do this without SharePoint Designer or any coding, importing or exporting. It's actually something SharePoint does really well.

To achieve this:

- Ensure both the list and library are on the *same site*.
- Navigate to either the "home" page (aka default page) of the site, or a custom page that allows webparts (e.g. /Pages/MyCustomDashboardPage.aspx) where you want to "combine" the two views
- Open the page in edit mode
- Click to add webparts, either from the page itself or the ribbon bar
- Find your list webpart and add it
- Add another webpart
- Find your library webpart and add it
- Arrange the webparts on the page however you'd like

Hope this helps!